# Calling setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree

Tags: flutter

I am creating a Flutter app, in one of its classes I am getting the exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _DetalleEmailEntranteScreenState#51a48(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
```

Here yoy have the initState part of it:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    checkSiAdmin();
    checkSiComercial();

    getEmailUsuarioActual();
    //  getNombreUsuarioActual();
    //  getApellidosUsuarioActual();
    getImagenUsuarioActual();
    getTelUsuarioActual();
    getIdUsuarioActual();
    getMiGrupoAdministrador();
    obtenerAdjuntosEmails();
    obtenerDestinatariosEmails();
    obtenerBodyEmails();


    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (Timer t) => refresh());
      });

    }

  }
```

And here the dispose part of it:

```
 @override
  void dispose() {
    timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

I don´t understand where is the issue?

Comment: I don't see your refresh method. Can you provide a full widget?

Comment: @Lucie, here you have:   Future<Null> refresh() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    setState(() {});
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Remove setState and try this:

```
if (mounted) {
      timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (Timer t) => refresh());
    }
```

Comment: The error persists